# Smartcard not recognized inside of Remmina instance

Tags: drivers, remote-desktop, remmina, smartcard

I am using `Remmina 1.4.12 (git 0ad90e24)` on my Ubuntu 18.04 and I have a connection to a remote desktop with Windows 10. I need to use the smartcard in my remote machine but Remmina does not recorgnize the smartcard driver nor the smartcard. I already checked the box "share smartcard" when I set up my connection. And the driver and card are correctly loaded inside my original machine. The software on my remote desktop that manages the smartcard driver is cryptovision 7.1.19.

Any suggestions what I can do to fix this problem and make my smartcard visible to the remote machine?

Comment: Had a similar problem with eToken. Eventually found out, that I need to instert smartcart into usb-port only _after_ connect to remote sever. Otherwise some error occurs on logon, and smartcard become disabled